# How may I get the desired output in my code?

Tags: python

I was attempting to solve some python excercise. I came across a question and that has made me feel bored. Please will you resolve it?

A school has following rules for grading system:

- Below 25 - F
- 25 to 45 - E
- 45 to 50 - D
- 50 to 60 - C
- 60 to 80 - B
- Above 80 - A

Ask user to enter marks and print the corresponding grade.

```
print("My mark is ")
a = input()

if '25 > a':
    print('F')

elif a < 25 and a > 45:
    print('E')

elif 45 <= a and a >|= 50:
    print('D')

elif 50 <= a and a >= 60:
    print('C')

elif 60 <= a and a >= 80:
    print('B')

else:
    print('A')
```

My expected result was different grades for different numbers but instead got only F for every input I do...

Comment: Each of your `if` is a string, remove the outside quotes.

Comment: your code is mal-indented. besides, why are you puting condition inside a quote? if '25 > a': is wrong. if(25<a): is correct, adding quote makes it a string not a bool anymore.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 an empty string is considered false right ?

Comment: An empty string is *falsy* but i dont see how thats relevant.

Comment: @Sayse was just clarifying ! It could be replaced at first `if` if OP wants to stick with strings

Answer (score 3):

```
print("My mark is ")
a = int(input())

if a < 25:
    print('F')
elif a >= 25 and a < 45:
    print('E')
elif a >= 45  and a < 50:
    print('D')
elif a >= 50 and a < 60:
    print('C')
elif a >= 60 and a < 80:
    print('B')
else:
    print('A')
```

first of all, you should cast input to int. then, you just compare it and "a" should be the first in comparing like a > 25, not 25 < a

Comment: Probably better to use `float` instead of `int` (I don’t think it will matter in this particular case, but in other cases you could get unexpected behavior). You could also remove all the `>=` expressions, since they will always be true at that point in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues..

Remove the outside quotes of your `if` statements as those are strings.
`elif '45 <= a and a => 50':` the order must be `>=`
And you must compare with an `int` so you need to do `int(input())` or another variation of converting to `int` type.

```py
a = int(input('What is the grade?'))

print("My mark is ")
if 25 > a:
    print('F')
elif a <= 25 and a > 45:
    print('E')
elif 45 <= a and a >= 50:
    print('D')
elif 50 <= a and a >= 60:
    print('C')
elif 60 <= a and a >= 80:
    print('B')
else:
    print('A')
```

Comment: But an integer can never be less than or equal to 25 AND greater than 45!

Answer (score 0):

your code needs a little clean up. Dont use quotation around the condition which is supposed to be Boolean

```
a = input("My mark is ")
a=int(a)
if (25 > a):
    print('F')    
elif a <= 25 and a > 45:
    print('E')  
elif 45 <= a and a >= 50:
    print('D')   
elif 50 <= a and a >= 60:
    print('C')    
elif 60 <= a and a >= 80:
    print('B')
else:
    print('A')
```

Comment: i didnt check it, i just formatted his.  but you are right, 'a' should be converted into int, to be able for integer evaluation